# Async file uploads with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs, remotipart

I have a form that uses rails jquery-UJS to submit asynchronously. It works fine as long as there is not a file input. When I add a file input, the form stops submitting asynchronously, and instead submits normally (full page reload).

I found out that since browsers do not support ajax files, UJS will fire the `ajax:aborted:file` event if a populated file input exists in the form. 
http://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs

The proposed solution is to use remotipart. https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart. However this gem hasn't been touched since 2013. I believe I read somewhere that Rails 4 includes this functionality.

What is the Rails 4 convention for async file uploads?

Comment: Did u even try to use `remotipart` gem? Doing a search in its issues list, it looks like some people have used it successfully with Rails 4. Not sure if it will work with latest version, but might be worth a try.

Comment: Checkout http://www.sitepoint.com/asynchronous-file-uploads-rails/, they use `remotipart` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: It seems that `remotipart` hooks into the the rails ujs and listens for the event.