# Display alert after form (file) upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form at `http://localhost:3000/` with data-remote='true', the purpose of which is to upload an image:

```
<form class="carousel" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/image_carousels/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="...">
  <input type="file" name="image_carousel[image]">
  <button name="button" type="submit">Submit Image</button>
</form>
```

The controller behaves as if the request were for html.  So if I make a view in image_carousels/update.html.erb as follows:

```
<p>Image Uploaded!</p>
```

This gets displayed at `http://localhost:3000/image_carousels/1`.

I'm confused as to why an html response is being expected and even displayed on a new page when I have set data-remote='true'.

Why is it behaving this way and, without changing the page, how do I:

1. Display a simple alert to the user to say the image has been uploaded
2. Return some json with {message: "Image uploaded successfully"} and then display the message to the user (for example's sake)
3. Return some html to be displayed after the form

(Some of these are just to improve my understanding)

Comment: Answer might be something to do with not being able to upload a file asynchronously.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24681837/async-file-uploads-with-rails-4

Answer (score 0):

Use `form_tag` and give `remote: true` 
example `<%= form_tag("/image_carousels/1", method: 'post', remote: true ) do %>`

In controller make response like below

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.js 
end
```

create file in views `upload.js.erb` and write a `alert` in this file. Just try this and tell me if you have any
 query

Comment: What's wrong with the form I've already produced? It has remote: true on it.

Comment: Yes that code should work. But why we have to use that approach? we have a `form_tag` right. But still if you want to use that approach then remove `accept-charset="UTF-8"` , just try it

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: I generated the form above using form_with.

Comment: Show your controller action